# Populating a list within a list in C# not using foreach loop. better way?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, list

I have a list of objects within a list of objects (List-ParentClass) that has as one of its objects a nested list (List-ChildClass).  To populate List-ChildClass I have used a foreach loop as shown below.  I have also nested a linq query as show below.

At this point I am having some performance issues and I feel like there is a better way to do this that I am just not finding.

Question:  How could I do this better/faster?

Note - This is a Web based .net MVC application written in C#.  I use EF back to a SQL database.

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public int pcid { get; set; }
    public List<ChildClass> ChildClassList { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    public int pcid { get; set; }
    public int ccid { get; set; }
}

public class DoWork 
{
    public void ExampleMethodForEach()
    {
        List<ParentClass> ParentClassList = new List<ParentClass>();

        foreach(ParentClass a in ParentClassList)
        {
            a.ChildClassList = EFDatabase2.where(b => b.pcid == a.pcid).select(b => b.ccid).ToList();
        }
    }

    public void ExampleMethodLinq()
    {
        var ParentClassList = (from a in EFDatabase
                               select new ParentClass
                               {
                                   ccid = a.ccid,
                                   pcid = (from b in EFDatabase2
                                           where b.pcid == a.pcid
                                           select b.ccid).ToList()
                                   //something like this were I nest a query
                               }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have performance issue with *database*, it´s *not* `list`, `foreach` etc but *database* to blame. What is the final query? How many records does the query fetch? In case of *list within list*, try doing as few calls as you can: can you fetch all data in *one go* and then organize them into structure you want?

Comment: What I had found with the foreach was the number of times it was hitting the database was possibly causing issues.  In my current app I am pulling the data over into memory then running, the foreach loop.  This performs better but seems like it is a little heavy haned.  I keep thinking that I could all be done in one big query.

Comment: As far as amount of records, it is relatively small, we are returning back a thousand or two, but then each has multiple lists that would contain 3 - 10x more records.  Also the queries to pull this are a bit more complicated.  So getting down into the details of my situation it is not maybe quite that simple.  Question: Do you think the above methods are normal/common ways of solving this situation?

Comment: So the total number of records (both parents and all the children) is about 10000-20000. It's not that many. Try to have the query as simple as you can, like `select b, parent_id from my_table` call it once and having data fetched create/fill your structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way when working with relational databases and LINQ is to use **joins** to correlate data. In your case, the most appropriate is [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx):

```
var ParentClassList =
    (from p in EFDatabase
     join c in EFDatabase2 on p.pcid equals c.pcid into children
     select new ParentClass
     {
         pcid = p.pcid,
         ChildClassList =
             (from c in children
              select new ChildClass
              {
                  pcid = c.pcid,
                  ccid = c.ccid
              }).ToList()
     }).ToList();
```

which should give you a nice fast single database query.

P.S. Hope your `EFDatabase` and `EFDatabase2` variables refer to two tables inside one and the same database.

Comment: This solution gave me the best performance.  Marking it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting your database multiple times. You have a N+1 issue.

What I suggest is to query all parents first, but excluding the children data. Then get the ID of all parents that you retrieved and put it inside an array. We will use that array to create a IN clause in SQL.

After loading all the children using the array of parent IDs, map them to a Lookup using `ToLookup` using the parent ID as the key and use a foreach to assign the list of children to the parent.

```
var parents = EFDatabase2.Parents.Where(...).Select(p => new ParentClass { pcid = p.pcid }).ToList();
var ids = parents.Select(p => p.pcid).ToArray();
var children = EFDatabase2.Children.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.ccid)).Select(c => new ChildClass { pcid = c.pcid, ccid = c.ccid }).ToLookup(c => c.pcid);

foreach (var parent in parents)
{
    parent.Children = children[parent.pcid];
}
```

In this case, you will only do two queries to your database.

Comment: That is very similar to what I am doing in a couple instances and the performance is "decent", however I think I am relying on linq and List too much.  I will try it like you have described.

Comment: It is very doubtful that you will get any real improvement in performance without LINQ and List. The probem is as Pierre-Alain said in your multiple DB queries. Best approach is to query everything from your database in one go (e.g. via stored procedure) and then map it to your data. Another thing you should verify is that you have proper indexes in your database for the queries, might be that your performance problem is there.